# OC @property with block in category

Tags: objective-c, properties, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

excuse me. I want to use block as my property in category to change my code style as follows, but there is something wrong and I don't know why.
Here is my code :
```

```
typedef NSString* (^MethodreplacingRangeWithString)(NSRange range,NSString * string);
typedef NSString* (^MethodAppend)(NSString *) ;
@interface NSString (Speech)
@property(nonatomic ,copy)MethodreplacingRangeWithString replacingRangeWithString ;
@property(nonatomic, copy)MethodAppend append ;
+(void)speech:(NSString *)content;
@end

@implementation NSString (Speech)

//setter and getter
static NSString * a = @"replacingRangeWithString" ;
-(void)setReplacingRangeWithString:(MethodreplacingRangeWithString)replacingRangeWithString{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(replacingRangeWithString), replacingRangeWithString, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC) ;
}
-(MethodreplacingRangeWithString)replacingRangeWithString{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(replacingRangeWithString)) ;
}

//setter and getter
static NSString * b = @"append" ;
-(void)setAppend:(MethodAppend)append{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(append), append,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC) ;
}
-(MethodAppend)append{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(append)) ;
}
//block
-(void)configureReplacingRangeWithStringProperty{
    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self ;
    self.replacingRangeWithString =  ^(NSRange range,NSString * str){
        return [weakSelf stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:str];
    };
}
-(void)configureAppend{
    __weak typeof (self)weakSelf = self ;
    self.append = ^(NSString *str){
        return [weakSelf stringByAppendingString:str] ;
    };
}
```

`to change the style as follows :`

```
NSString * str = @"hello world" ;
        [str configureAppend] ;
        [str configureReplacingRangeWithStringProperty] ;
        str = str.replacingRangeWithString(NSMakeRange(6, 5),@"iOS").append(@" hhhhh") ;
```

```

here is sth wrong with my configures and I don't know why

Comment: it seems that the configures are wrong.

Comment: when I run code
```
    NSString * str = @"hello world" ;
            [str configureAppend] ;
            [str configureReplacingRangeWithStringProperty] ;
            str = str.replacingRangeWithString(NSMakeRange(6, 
    5),@"iOS").append(@" hhhhh") ;
```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

Comment: why is that ? i wonder

Comment: Step through your code using the debugger and check if all your variables are real and have a value. Is `str` still correct after each step?

Comment: it cannot run when use str = str.replacingRangeWithString(NSMakeRange(6, 5),@"iOS").append(@" hhhhh") ; why is it???

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? It looks very complicated to just replace part of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the actual crash you are getting is probably down to a misunderstanding of associated objects. When you associate an object you do so to a *specific instance*, not to all instances of the same type.

Looking at your code:

```
[str configureAppend] ;
[str configureReplacingRangeWithStringProperty] ;
```

At this point you have associated two objects with the particular instance that `str` is referring to. Now you try to do:

```
str = str.replacingRangeWithString(NSMakeRange(6, 5),@"iOS").append(@" hhhhh") ;
```

Breaking this up:

```
str.replacingRangeWithString
```

This invokes the property `replacingRangeWithString` on whatever object instance `str` is referencing. Let's call that object A. Now your previous two statements associated objects with A, so this works and you get your block reference back.

```
str.replacingRangeWithString(NSMakeRange(6, 5),@"iOS")
```

This invokes the block and returns a *different* string, call that object B.

```
str.replacingRangeWithString(NSMakeRange(6, 5),@"iOS").append
```

This invokes the property `append` on object B, you have associated no objects with object B so this returns a null reference.

```
str.replacingRangeWithString(NSMakeRange(6, 5),@"iOS").append(@" ahhhh")
```

You attempt to call your "block", but you have a null reference => memory fault.

**Update**

At this point I originally suggested that you need to rethink your design - you do - and that a solution might not be as simple as you might like - and since then it dawned on me that there might be a simple approach...

*Provided* you are just trying to replace method calls with property accesses so you can neatly chain calls together; i.e. that you've no intention of calling your `configure...` methods with blocks which perform different operations; then you can dynamically create and return a block in your property. Here is the outline for `append`. First make the property read only:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) MethodAppend append;
```

and then define it using:

```
-(MethodAppend)append
{
   NSString *copied = self.copy;
   return ^(NSString *string){ return [copied stringByAppendingString:string]; };
}
```

This first copies the string in case the instance it is called on is an `NSMutableString`, you don't know how long after this property is invoked that the block will be called and the string value could have been changed by that point. Then it returns a block which accepts the required arguments and calls the intended method.

That is all that is required, no setters or configure methods, and no associate objects.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much! And I also want to ask what is the effect of ` self.copy`?

Comment: To make a copy of the string (this is an instance method on `NSString` so `self` is the string) in case the actual instance the method is called on is an `NSMutableString`. The effect is to ensure that the block returns performs an append with the value of the string as it was when the property was called. This is the same reasoning as why `NSString` typed properties should always be declared with the `copy` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the properties as `copy` and then implement `strong` setters.

More likely than not, your crash is because you have a block on the stack that is being used after the stack frame is destroyed.

Comment: how to deal with that ?

Comment: Use `block_copy()` in your setter implementations.